# What do you call a person who is seeking endorsement (or approval)?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

My actual paragraph is:

> arXiv required endorsement for people without an institutional email address. And that endorser has to have at least two papers in the same field as the ______ .

Fill in the blank, please.

Comment: the endorsee, perhaps?

Comment: Is this an application for some thing? So perhaps *Applicant* ?

Comment: I'd be inclined to use "supplicant", as a generic term, or perhaps "suppliant".  "Petitioner" is another possibility.

Answer (score 2):

If the first person is being called the *endorser* then that person must actually be endorsing the second.  In that case, the second person is the *endorsee*.

> Noun: **endorsee**  (en,dor'see)
>
> The person to whom something is transferred by endorsement
>
> Derived forms: endorsees

-- [WordWebOnline](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=endorsee)

Comment: This may work if a definition suitable to the context can be provided. It appears that the one given here talks about the legal transfer of property/money.

Answer (score 2):

[***candidate***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/candidate)

`3. a person or thing regarded as suitable or likely for a particular fate or position: "This wine is a candidate for his cellar."`

> The endorser has to have at least two papers in the same field as the ***candidate***.